# Is 'publish_actions' extended permissions available for testing?

Tags: permissions, facebook-authentication

I've been trying to test out Scores and Achievements using the 'publish_actions' extended permissions but when I add it, it doesn't show up in the Request for Permission page.  It's like its ignored.

I've tried a couple different ways:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_actions', 'canvas' => 1,    'fbconnect' => 0, 'redirect_uri'=>config_item('facebook_url')));

$loginUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' 
  . 'client_id=' . config_item('fbappid')
  . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode(config_item('facebook_url'))
  . '&state=' . $_SESSION['state']
  . '&scope=publish_actions';
```

Both way don't work.  Has anyone else had any luck testing this out?

Referencing code here:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/?ref=nf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ran into the same problem yesterday.

i think fb will change this behaviour in the near future, but currently it seems that the app must be in the category 'game' to request the 'publish_actions' permission... (i am in the sandbox mode)

Comment: So strange. Any idea how Spotify can have done this without being in the category 'game'? 

(First they don't ask for the activity permission; there seems to be a second dialog.)

Comment: You were right.  My main app was in the game category, but my test app wasn't.  Now that I switched my test app to game, it works.  Thank you!

Comment: looks a little chaotic right now at fb. look at http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications i was a bit surprised about the permissions the applications that i have added decades ago currently have (most of them had *all*, and i am very confident, that i have never allowed that...)

Comment: You should also be able to do this if you enable the new style auth dialog for testing

Comment: @Bytepirate: if the apps were added a very long time ago before the permissions model for apps was tightened up they may have asked for an old permission which was subsequently split into several 'sub' permissions

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this same issue here is what you need to do.

1) Go to the apps page https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and select your app

2) On the left nav bar under Settings got to Auth Dialog

3) At the bottom of this page click on Configure how Facebook refers users to your app

4) You should now be able to add publish_actions
 permissions.[image]

5) Read the following links (its a pain to find)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/

Comment: Just to be clear, that setting is only for authenticated referrals.

Answer (score 4):

this might help as well (quoting facebook):

> "While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only
>   be requested from developers and test users of your app. The
>   'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any
>   other user."

it only comes up after updating the permissions inside the app configuration. lost so much time because of this lacking documantation...

Comment: Yeah, what a waste of my time!  The message is extremely hard to find (on the auth dialog settings of your app) and now it says "Please note that the 'publish_actions' permission will only be visible to the developers and testers of your app, until your actions are approved."