# Testing "publish_actions" in Facebook app

Tags: facebook, permissions

How do I configure my Facebook app so that I can test "publish_actions"?

[Is 'publish_actions' extended permissions available for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540806/is-publish-actions-extended-permissions-available-for-testing)

[How can I request the "publish_actions" permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022510/how-can-i-request-the-publish-actions-permission)

The above two questions are identical, but the answers are out of date; they are all from the beta version of the Open Graph API and the introduction of the "publish_actions" permission.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are added with the login code using parameter `scope`. [Details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0)

After adding the permission the admin/developers/testers of the app can test your application and publish posts; while app is in development mode.

When your app is ready submit your app for the [login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login). After they approve your app with this permission, you can make your app public and everybody can publish post using your app. That's it.

Comment: My problem has been getting the feature to work correctly for the review process. I finally figured out how to add the permission to a test user using the Graph Explorer in the Developer console. How do I request the permission when the user logs in?

Comment: Will the permission be requested automatically after my app is approved to use it?

Comment: Nope. As I have mentioned the answer that the permissions are added with the `scope` parameter in your **Login** code. Adding permissions to the Graph API Explorer is just for test. Just add `scope` in the Login with the required permission `publish_action`. Check out the link *"Details here"* I've added in the answer

Comment: Thanks. The quotes around `scope` help the first sentence make a lot more sense!

Comment: I still haven't quite solved my problem. I am probably not asking the right questions, though.

Comment: I gave this answer an upvote. I just haven't decided whether or not to accept it yet.

Comment: Cool. But let me know on what part you are still stuck on

Comment: Thanks for offering your help. I'm actually using a third-party library for Android called socialauth-android. I'm having difficulty getting it to request the "publish_actions" permission. Their example works fine for me until I change the keys to my own app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Same problem, I added publish_actions to the scope parameters however it does not add them when the test user logs in. I'm in development mode currently and have not request approval.

Comment: @tomjung Are you experiencing like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700838/cant-request-facebook-login-api-permission-publish-actions-even-for-primary-a#comment47546595_29700838