# Can't request Facebook Login API permission "publish_actions" even for primary administrator

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-permissions

I'm implementing Facebook login with an extended permission [`publish_actions`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-publish_actions) using [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0). It shows a message in the login dialog even if I signed in with my primary administrator account:

> Submit for Login Review. Some of the permissions below have not been
>   approved for use by Facebook

I have the following code snippet to post to the user timeline.

```
try {
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
            'message' => 'This is test post.'
        )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I executed the code, I got the error

> Exception occured, code: 200 with message: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

According to [the Facebook login review documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login), it is not required to submit a login review for the app's developer accounts.

> However, in order to help you craft your Facebook Login experience,
>   your app's developers will be able to see, and grant, any permission
>   without requiring review by Facebook.
>
> Note: People who are listed in your app's Roles tab will have access
>   to extended permissions without going through review (e.g.
>   `publish_actions` or `manage_pages`).

I added another administrator account and a developer account into the app Roles tab setting and let them try, but still encountering the same problem.

My app status is live. I'm testing it from the local site with virtual host such as mysite.local, but it shouldn't be a problem since I could add it in the app setting.

Comment: The message only tells you that you need to submit for review, before you can ask common users for the permission. Did you actually proceed to the _second_ screen of the login dialog? Publishing permission is only asked for there.

Comment: @CBroe I requested the permissions `public_profile`, `email`, `user_friends`, `publish_actions`. In the *first* screen of the login dialog, I see the red-bordered message "Submit for Login Review. Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook". After I clicked "Edit the info you provide", I see only three permissions - Public profile (required), Friend list, Email address. OH I SEE. It is because I clicked "Not Now" in the *second* screen. I thought it was asking me to post about this login connect information. This was my stupid. Thank you.